# Restart service on file change

Tags: haproxy, ubuntu-14.04

I would like HAProxy on my Ubuntu 14.04 to restart each time I SCP a new HAProxy config file.  What is the easiest/cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you considered so far, and why did you consider it insufficient?

Answer (score 4):

Use inotify to monitor the file change and have it execute a script or command that does the haproxy config reload or a full restart.

https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264238/restart-process-on-file-change-in-linux